# Statistics of database entries in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, statistics, activeadmin

I am wondering if there is any pre written `gem` for `rails 4` project which shows the analytics on database (model) for e.g how many order received today? yesterday? last month?. How many users created profile, etc. etc. Maybe shows a nice graph of orders over a period or something.

Comment: there are. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/graphing

Answer (score 0):

You can start using [Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info/) which gives you an interface for all your models.

Alternatively, you can implement custom graphs in no time after investing 15 minutes into [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts).

Comment: @BhushanLodha I apologize. I was missing the http:// prefix, so Stackoverflow did not render it as a link.